# mysql 5.5 equivalent to v5.7 SHUTDOWN?

Tags: mysql

I have to perform a shutdown on a server with mysql 5.5.53. I was used to v5.7 SHUTDOWN.

I think the old command is mysql_shutdown() (confirm?), but my main concern, is that usually after a SHUTDOWN, it will restart as soon as called, but I don't know if it'll be the same after using a 5.5 mysql_shutdown. At this point you'll for sure noticed I'm not exactly a mysql ninja.. :P

Answer (score 2):

It's simply not available earlier, so in older versions you will need the 'normal' way to shut down mysql. The best way is generally to use whatever your operating system provides.

On my OS, it's `service mysql stop`. Note that by default generally only admins can do this, so you'll also need a way to escalate permissions.